# Positive integer sequence of polynomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Set an even integer $n \geq 2$. Does there exist an infinite sequence of positive integers $a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$ such that for every integer $i \geq 0$, every polynomial $\Sigma_{j=0}^n a_{i+j}x^{n-j}$ has a real root?

This problem was inspired by generalizing the quadratic case (which can be solved by inspecting the discriminant - the answer is no). I do not know the answer to this problem.

---

Solution to $n = 2$ (the quadratic case):

Suppose such a sequence existed. Then the discriminant of the quadratic $a_ix^2+a_{i+1}x+a_{i+2}$, which is $a_{i+1}^2-4a_ia_{i+2}$ must be non-negative, or else the quadratic doesn't have a real solution. Rearranging the inequality $a_{i+1}^2-4a_ia_{i+2} \geq 0$ we can get $\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} \geq 4\frac{a_{i+2}}{a_{i+1}}$.

Let $\frac{a_1}{a_0} = D < 4^K$, for some sufficiently large $K$. Then $a_n = \frac{a_1}{a_0} \cdot \frac{a_2}{a_1} \cdots  \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$ has an upper bound of $D \cdot \frac{D}{4} \cdot \frac{D}{16} \cdots \frac{D}{4^{n-1}} < 4^{Kn-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}}$. Now let $n = 2K +1$ and we conclude that $a_{2K+1} < 1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you share your solution for the quadratic case?

Comment: For the case where n=2  we can see that $P(x)=a_1x^{2}+a_2x+a3$ if $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are positive, then the proposition is false of course.

Comment: @NoChance But the contention is that no sequence works when $n=2$, not that some sequence doesn't work.

Comment: @MathTrain solution to n=2 posted